# Selecting column based on variable using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can look up more information on this statement.

This is a stored procedure that has two strings passed in @loc_nbr and @loc_type. It seems that the column to search the @loc_nbr is selected based on the @loc_type string that is passed in. Can anyone explain this to me or better yet just point me to the reference page as I'm having trouble finding more information.

```
where @loc_nbr = 
case when @loc_type = 'Chain' then @loc_nbr
    when @loc_type = 'Operation' then operation_nbr
    when @loc_type = 'Region' then region_nbr
    when @loc_type = 'Area' then area_nbr
    when @loc_type = 'District' then district_nbr
    when @loc_type = 'Store' then C2.str_nbr end
```

I'm confused on how the case statement works in this situation in relation to the WHERE clause. How is the column searched against? the THEN in this case is a column (operation_nbr, region_nbr) while @loc_nbr is a varchar

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Do you not understand what a `case` expression does?

Comment: It's a `CASE` **expression** not a `Case` (`Switch`) statement; T-SQL doesn't support the latter. Though, personally, I suggest against this type of `WHERE`; stick to `OR` and `AND`s.

Comment: Something like `where (@loc_type = 'Chain') or (@loc_type = 'Operation' and @loc_nbr = operation_nbr) or (@loc_type = 'Region' and @loc_nbr = region_nbr)...`

Comment: I'm confused on how the case statement works in this situation in relation to the WHERE clause. How is the column searched against? the THEN in this case is a column while @loc_nbr is a varchar.

Comment: @Larnu do you assert that SQLS doesn't allow `CASE x WHEN 1 THEN ... WHEN 2 THEN...` ?

Comment: Thats is a `CASE` **expression** (bold for emphasis again) @CaiusJard. I explicitly stated T-SQL (not SQL, as every dialect is different, so some may) does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements. I never said T-SQL doesn't support `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite straight forward, I'll do my best to explain.

First off the `case` expression.

`case when <some expression=true> then return this else that end`

When there are several `case - when` statements in a single `case` expression it will evaluate each in turn and return on the first expression that evaluates `true`.

The `where` clause evaluates an expression for every row, if the expression is `true` the row is returned otherwise it's excluded.

You could have `where 1=1` - that evaluates `true` for every row, so all rows are returned.

If you have two variables, `@a` and `@b`, and set them both to `1` then `where @a=@b` is identical to `where @b=@a` and all rows are returned.

In the same way, `where 1 = case when 1=1 then 1 else 0 end` will return all rows - the `case` expression is evaluated, does 1 equal 1? Yes, so the expression returns `1` and it equals the `1` on the other side of the `=` so the `where` clause is `true` for all rows.

Now consider the following,

`where @loc_nbr = case when @loc_type='chain' then @loc_nbr else 1 end`

If `@loc_type` does contain 'chain' then the `case` expression is `true` and it returns `@loc_nbr`, in which case we have`where @loc_nbr=@loc_nbr` is `true` for all rows and no filtering is done. If `@loc_type` is anything else, we have `where @loc_nbr=1` so any individual row is only returned if the value of `@loc_nbr` is `1`.

So now you can start to introduce values from columns into the `case` expression.

```
where @loc_nbr =
  case when @loc_type = 'Chain' then @loc_nbr <------------No filtering done, all rows returned, essentially where 1=1
       when @loc_type = 'Operation' then operation_nbr <---A row is returned only if the value of column operation_nbr = @loc_nbr
  end
```

So you can see you can just continue to add additional `when` clauses, and only the column specified for the value of `@loc_type` is used to compare with `@loc_nbr`. Each row is returned if the value of that column equals `@Loc_nbr`

`@Loc_nbr` can be a string, the column in your table, `operation_nbr, region_nbr` etc can be `integer` and if `@loc_nbr` is a string it will be implicitly cast to an `int` for the comparison. It would be better to explicitly cast them for clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail explanation.  I don't know why this syntax had me so stuck, your explanation makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would make more sense to you if it looked like this:

```
where 
  (@loc_type = 'Chain') OR
  (@loc_type = 'Operation' AND operation_nbr = @loc_nbr) OR
  (@loc_type = 'Region' AND region_nbr = @loc_nbr) OR
  (@loc_type = 'Area' AND area_nbr = @loc_nbr) OR
  (@loc_type = 'District' AND district_nbr = @loc_nbr) OR
  (@loc_type = 'Store' AND C2.str_nbr = @loc_nbr)
```

They are, in essence, the same logic

Comment: Thank you, this syntax is much to understand!

Comment: There's a chance it'll be faster too - database is more likely able to use indexes with this one, than the other form